# `systemd stop <myservice>` works fine but the service hangs on `shutdown -H now`. Help me undertand what's happening?

Tags: systemd

I've got a service `myservice` which spins some containers with `docker-compose`. I'm able to start and stop it fine with `systemctl`. However, when the system is being shut down or reboot it hangs for about 2 minutes before it's able to to do it. The hang doesn't happen if I manually stop the service with `systemctl` before attempted shutdown/reboot.

Unfortunately because of the way the system is built and configured (it's a custom embedded build) getting the journal to persist across reboots is non-trivial, so I can't easily inspect what actually happens at boot.

I'm looking for any hints about what might be different between the service being stopped at shutdown vs with `systemctl stop myservice`.

Here's the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Myservice Description
After=network.target syslog.target docker.service
Requires=docker.service
RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/data/where_docker_volumes_live

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/opt/some_prep_script.sh
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose --project-directory /opt/mycontainers up --force-recreate
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker-compose --project-directory /opt/mycontainers down
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I bet the docker daemon has been shut down before your service was stopped, and that didn't trigger your service to be shut down because you forgot to define a dependency on docker. But that's **just guessing**. I must say, I find it quite obvious that in a question like yours, you'd include the service file to not let people guess...

Comment: There is a dependency on docker. I'll update the question to include the service file.